# file upload dialog with multiselect

Tags: html, file-upload, dialog, internet-explorer-9

I'm working on a file upload solution that adds flexibility to existing options. A standard  works fine, but does not allow selecting multiple files. There are plenty of solutions to work around this, I'm aware of that, but I'm looking at the solution Facebook has implemented. the "multiple=true" moniker isn't supported by IE9 and below; Facebook trick this by providing a file dialog (on IE) that allows multiselect and feed the result back to a flash upload handler. My question is: how do I open that file dialog (allowing multiselect)? Once I get that done, I can handle the results from there (sending multiple files to my upload handler isn't a problem, nor is distinguishing between IE9 and other browsers/platforms).

Comment: I believe the multi-select file dialog is spawned by the Flash applet itself.

Comment: I believe you are right. Is there a way to achieve this without said flash applet?